# How to change caret (cursor) blinking rate in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, text-cursor

How to change caret (cursor) blinking rate in NetBeans? (7.0)

NetBeans developers say that this is supported as a Swing option, see [Bug 124211 - Cursor blink rate too fast](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=124211) but I can't figure out the name of this Swing option to set from the command line.

The closest example of setting Swing option that I found is setting look and feel by putting 
`-J-Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel` to the netbeans.conf.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a module for customizing the Cursor Blinking Rate created by Emilian Bold, but that module is not found easily available.  Let me provide a less intuitive way but this solution works with NetBeans IDE 7.0.1 as tested by me.

1. Make sure the NetBeans IDE is shut down before making these changes.
2. Create file `<userdir>/config/Editors/text/x-java/properties.xml`
   Here the `<userdir>` means the User directory used by NetBeans IDE.  This directory can be found from the NetBeans **Help > About** menu.  The `config` folder will already be there in this directory but the folders `Editors/text/x-java` may not be there and we will have to create them, they are case sensitive.  The `properties.xml` file shall also be created in the `x-java` folder.
3. Add the following contents to the `properties.xml` file

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <!DOCTYPE properties PUBLIC "-//NetBeans//DTD Editor Properties settings
     1.0//EN" "http://www.netbeans.org/dtds/EditorProperties-1_0.dtd">
     <properties>
         <property class="java.lang.Integer" name="caret-blink-rate" value="0"/>
     </properties>
```

1. The value="0" portion can be customized by desired blink rate in miliseconds, the default value used by NetBeans IDE is 300 in my opinion, but it can be changed with a new value, 0 will mean no blinking.
2. Start NetBeans IDE again and now you will get your desired blink rate for the cursor in Java files.

Comment: Thank you, works great. To change the blink rate for other file types, I just had to create another folder under the "text" folder; eg I created a "javascript" folder beside the "x-java" folder, and copied the "properties.xml" file into it, so all my JavaScript files now use the specified rate. Thanks!

Comment: Can this be applied at a higher scope?  Or does it need to be done for each mime type?

Comment: According to my knowledge for now you have to do this customization for each MIME type.

Answer (score 20):

I realize this is old, but it's quite high up in google search so I thought I'd add an updated solution. The solution above by Tushar Joshi does not work for me in Netbeans 7.1.1. What I had to do, was quite similar though:

Basically, the setting have moved to `<userdir>\config\Editors\text\x-java\Preferences\org-netbeans-modules-editor-settings-CustomPreferences.xml`.

The path for Unix/Linux is `$HOME/.netbeans/<NetbeansVersion>/config/Editors/Preferences/org-netbeans-modules-editor-settings-CustomPreferences.xml`.

Exit netbeans and modify the file by adding the entry

```
<entry javaType="java.lang.Integer" name="caret-blink-rate" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>1000</value>
</entry>
```

The `value` is the number of milliseconds of blink rate. I added a whole second. I added it so it lined up alphabetically with the other name properties of the other entries, but I don't know if that's important or not. That's it:)

Comment: Yes, it works for my Netbeans 8.0. I wish it could read the system's setting for the blink rate. All other apps (e.g. Notepad) on my Windows blinks with same rate, why Netbeans can't? May be someone could log a bug for it.

Comment: I'm also using Netbeans 7.4 but setting the value to 0 doesn't prevent it from blinking. :(

Comment: Zero value doesn't disable blinking in NetBeans 8.2. Use 2147483647 (24.8 days) instead.

Comment: This works. Thanks.
Anyone curious default interval for Windows is 530 milliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to disable it for *all* editors, instead of just the Java editor, add the following:

```
<entry javaType="java.lang.Integer" name="caret-blink-rate" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>2147483647</value>
</entry>
```

under the `<editor-preferences>` element to the file:

```
config/Editors/Preferences/org-netbeans-modules-editor-settings-CustomPreferences.xml
```

The full paths are:

On Mac:

```
~/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/8.2/config/Editors/Preferences/org-netbeans-modules-editor-settings-CustomPreferences.xml
```

On Windows:

```
%APPDATA%\NetBeans\8.2\config\Editors\Preferences\org-netbeans-modules-editor-settings-CustomPreferences.xml
```

Source: https://forums.netbeans.org/topic9561.html